# Why is removing list items in a for loop not working correctly?

Tags: python, list

Why does not every `0` get removed from the list?

```
list = [0,0,5,3,0,8,0,4] 

for num in list:
    if num == 0:
        list.remove(0)

print(list)
```

Comment: Actually, it's because you're changing the size of `list`, while iterating over it. This is never a good idea. It's also not a good idea to shadow the `list` keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) So either use a list comprehension or use a copy of your list.

Comment: The title of the question is irrelevant. You have nothing related to indexes in the question

Answer (score 4):

Because you are mutating the list while looping over it, and that is almost always a bad idea. Here's a demonstration of what happens:

```
list = [0,0,5,3,0,8,0,4] 

for num in list:
    print(num, list)
    if num == 0:
        list.remove(0)

print(list)
```

> Output
>
> ```
> 0 [0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 4]
> 5 [0, 5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 4]
> 3 [0, 5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 4]
> 0 [0, 5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 4]
> 0 [5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 4]
> [5, 3, 8, 0, 4]
> ```

And here's a relevant section from the documenation, which tells that this is bad idea:

> **Note:** There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
>   loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, e.g. lists). An
>   internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and
>   this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached
>   the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop. This can lead to nasty
>   bugs that can be avoided by making a temporary copy using a slice of
>   the whole sequence, e.g.,
>
> ```
> for x in a[:]:
>     if x < 0: a.remove(x)
> ```
>
> [**Source**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

You can use a very simple list comprehension to make this work:

```
list_ = [0,0,5,3,0,8,0,4]  # list shadows the built-in name, don't use it
list_ = [num for num in list_ if num != 0]
print(list_)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [5, 3, 8, 4]
> ```